# Java 2D Arrays string or char Seating managment

Tags: java, arrays, 2d

I have the assignment in java by using an array and here some instruction in how to write the program. 
**the problem I faced in step 2 how should initialize the array to show the output like below ( 1 A B C D ).**

Write a java program for the seating arrangement. The program should have the following

1/ Ask the user to enter how many row in the seating arrangement (Done)

2/ Depending upon the entered row, use arrays and loops to assign the initial seat
numbering and display as follows:

```
     Example if you enter ----- > row = 3
     The display will be:
      1 A B C D
      2 A B C D
      3 A B C D
```

3/ Ask the user to choose the seat they want and the assigned ‘X’ for the chosen seat. (Done)
The user will be ask to enter until a sentinel value is given to stop entering.

4/ Display the seat patterns after the assigned value of ‘X’

```
 Example if the user choose ----- > 1A 2B 3D
    The display will be:
   1 X B C D
   2 A X C D
   3 A B C X
```

**I wrote the code but in a problem, I faced problem in 2D arrays, I didn't know how to initialize the arrays it's a String or char array?**

**my code**

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter how many row in seating arrangment: ");
        int rowNo = s.nextInt();

        String seating[][] = new String[rowNo][4];
        for (int i = 0; i < rowNo; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
                if (j == 0)
                    seating[i][j] = "A";
                else if (j == 1)
                    seating[i][j] = "B";
                else if (j == 2)
                    seating[i][j] = "C";
                else
                    seating[i][j] = "D";
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < rowNo; i++) {
            System.out.println(i + 1);
            for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
                System.out.println((j + 1) + "\t" + seating[i][j]);
            }
            System.out.println();
        }

        String askUser = "Y";
        while (askUser.equalsIgnoreCase("Y")) {
            System.out.println("Chose your Seat ");

            System.out.println("Enter the row  ");
            int row = s.nextInt();

            System.out.println("Enter the column  ");
            String col = s.nextLine();

            if (col.equals("A"))
                seating[row - 1][0] = "X";
            else if (col.equals("B"))
                seating[row - 1][1] = "X";
            else if (col.equals("C"))
                seating[row - 1][2] = "X";
            else
                seating[row - 1][3] = "X";

            System.out.println("Contnioe to choose seat [y -Yes | n-No] :");
            askUser = s.next();
        }

        System.out.println("Find Seating");
        for (int i = 0; i < rowNo; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
                System.out.println((j + 1) + "\t" + seating[i][j]);
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

***the output of my code***

```
     Enter how many row in seating arrangment: 

    3
    1
    1   A
    2   B
    3   C
    4   D

    2
    1   A
    2   B
    3   C
    4   D

  Chose your Seat 
  Enter the row  
   2
  Enter the column  
  A
  Contnioe to choose seat [y -Yes | n-No] :

 Find Seating
 1  A
 2  B
 3  C
 4  D

1   A
2   B
3   C
4   X
```

what's the error in my code ?
**Hint by Teacher: The row numbers should be stored in one-dimensional string array. 
A 2D array should be used for the characters.**

I'm looking for help, please.
regards

but the 2d array if i do it like this is correct?

```
 String seatRow[]= new String[rowNo];
 char [] col= {'A','B','C','D'};
//String[] col= {"a b c d "};
String s=Arrays.toString(col);
String SeatAval[][]= new String [rowNo][s.length()];
```

I confused about the hint provided by teacher set the row in a string array. and characters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've edited your code to work and added notes so you know what was going wrong. Please read and understand. Also you should probably add some error checking in case the user gives bad inputs. Here is the updated code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter number of rows in seating arrangment: ");
        int rowNo = s.nextInt();

        String[][] seating = new String[rowNo][4];
        for (int i = 0; i < rowNo; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
                if (j == 0)
                    seating[i][j] = "A";
                else if (j == 1)
                    seating[i][j] = "B";
                else if (j == 2)
                    seating[i][j] = "C";
                else
                    seating[i][j] = "D";
            }
        }

        // Extracted your printing into a method
        printSeating(seating);

        String askUser = "Y";
        while (askUser.equalsIgnoreCase("Y")) {
            System.out.println("Chose your Seat ");

            System.out.println("Enter the row  ");
            int row = s.nextInt();
            // nextInt() only gets the int and doesn't consume the newline
            // so this consumes the newline
            s.nextLine();

            System.out.println("Enter the column  ");
            String col = s.nextLine();

            if (col.equals("A"))
                seating[row - 1][0] = "X";
            else if (col.equals("B"))
                seating[row - 1][1] = "X";
            else if (col.equals("C"))
                seating[row - 1][2] = "X";
            else
                seating[row - 1][3] = "X";

            System.out.println("Contnioe to choose seat [y -Yes | n-No] :");
            askUser = s.next();
        }

        System.out.println("Find Seating");
        // Extracted your printing into a method
        printSeating(seating);
    }


    private static void printSeating(String[][] seating) {
        for (int i = 0; i < seating.length; i++) {
            // Don't print a newline, since you want to continue printing on this line
            System.out.print(i + 1);
            for (int j = 0; j < seating[i].length; j++) {
                // Don't print a newline, since you want to continue printing on this line
                System.out.print(" " + seating[i][j]);
            }
            // now you print a newline
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Aha , the code works thank you very much.  so the error in printing :( .

Comment: @AshwaqFaisal Yep, was mostly just an error in the printing. If this helped you then please accept the answer. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry may ask how to check if the seat reserved or not?